# Spring boot JSON config return null

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to add this JSON as an external configuration for my Spring boot project:

```
{
    "napas":[
        {
            "bankId":1,
            "name":"abc",
            "napasName":"xyz",
            "napasId":"111"
        },
        {
            "bankId":2,
            "name":"mnk",
            "napasName":"tcb",
            "napasId":"2222"
        },
        {
            "bankId":3,
            "name":"qwer",
            "napasName":"tyu",
            "napasId":"888"
        }
    ]
}
```

this is my configuration class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:napas-config.json", factory = JsonPropertySourceFactory.class)
public class NapasConfig {
    private List<Napas> napas;
}
```

And this is my object:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Napas {
    private String bankId;
    private String name;
    private String napasName;
    private String napasId;
}
```

Of course, there is a Json property source factory for binding, I think that error comes from here but I'm not sure how to fix it:

```
public class JsonPropertySourceFactory implements PropertySourceFactory {

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource encodedResource) throws IOException {
        Map readValue = new ObjectMapper().readValue(encodedResource.getInputStream(), Map.class);
        return new MapPropertySource(encodedResource.getResource().getFilename(), readValue);
    }
}
```

When I inject `NapasConfig` into my service, and call `getNapas()` list, it returns null! Can someone explain why and how to fix this!

Comment: Why are you doing this so complicated? You could simply read the json file

Comment: yes! but this is the way our project is doing! Sad to say that! But it's nice to understand why it doesn't work..

Answer (score -1):

You missed an important annotation `@ConfigurationProperties` to make your class a configuration properties class

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Configuration
// This was missing
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "")
//
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:napas-config.json", factory = JsonPropertySourceFactory.class)
public class NapasConfig {
    private List<Napas> napas;
}
```

Comment: `Configuration` and `ConfigurationProperties` are two very different things that can't be used together.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar What are you telling! The example works as expected

Comment: Really? With his code? It’d be a new learning for me.

Comment: And @AbhijitSarkar Please read the documentation https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar And please don't down answers without proving that it's wrong. Thank you

Comment: What documentation? If there’s something specific, feel free to point it out.

Comment: Checkout out the link https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot and also the reference documentation:

Comment: You’re assuming I downvoted you. If I’m wrong, I’m happy to stand corrected. No need to get upset because you lost 2 points, get over it, this isn’t a competition.